# Рассчитать величины тегов и индексов для кэш-памяти

Tags: кэширование, архитектура

Помогите решить задачу

Рассчитать величины тегов и индексов для кэш-памяти (полностью ассоциативной, с прямым отображением, 2х и 4х направленной частично ассоциативной) при следующих исходных данных : величина блока 8 байт, адресуемая память 1024 Мбайт, размер кэш 64 Кбайт
Расчитала для 2х и 4х направленной, неуверенна, что верно log2(Smemoru*A/Scache), А- канальность, а как остальное посчитать